# is_authenticated is always True even after remove all user's sessions

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Using Django, I'm trying to login out a user but in server side as I'm using Django just for backend as our frontend is developed useing Reactjs + Node, and my problem is related when I try to login out the user. This is what I'm doing for this:

```
    from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
    for s in Session.objects.all():
        data = s.get_decoded()
        if data.get('_auth_user_id', None) == str(user.id):
            s.delete()
    auth.logout(context)
```

the problem is that even when the logout code is executed, if I call the logout API again, user.is_authenticated is always True.

What do I have to do to receive False without checking the Session table manually to detect if the user is loged in ir not?

Regards

Comment: What is 'context'?

Comment: Where are you checking is_authenticated? What is the user object at that point?

Comment: @pissall context is the request, after the code exposed above i'm doing print(user) and it prints the username which in this case is freddy, and after that, I added a second print which is print(user.is_authenticated) and it prints True. That's why I say that is still True is_authenticated call